# Extract dataframe with regex

Tags: regex, python-3.x, pandas

Here is a code to get all 2xx response_code from dataframe but it tells me error to put "extracct" instead...

The dataframe is like

```
date_time   response_code
 2/3/10         202
 2/6/10         200
 2/3/12         300
 2/3/11         202
```

Code :

```
df_2xx = df_light.response_code.astype(str).str.contains('(2[0-9][0-9])')
```

I need

```
date_time   response_code
 2/3/10         202
 2/6/10         200
 2/3/11         202
```

thanks you !

Comment: https://datatofish.com/select-rows-pandas-dataframe/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use boolean index:

```
df_light[df_light['response_code'].astype(str).str.contains('2[0-9][0-9]')]
```

Output:

```
  date_time  response_code
0    2/3/10            202
1    2/6/10            200
3    2/3/11            202
```

or:

```
df_light[df_light['response_code'].astype(str).str.startswith('2')]
```

or:

```
df_light[df_light['response_code'] % 200 < 100]
```